# sqoop mysql primary key null

Tags: hive, sqoop, data-synchronization

I use sqoop to export a table in mysql to hive.
When job complete, I check the record number and found number of records in hive is much more than in mysql.

I further check the primary key of data in hive, and found many null values.

Can any one help explain why this happened? Is that possible that these null values are caused by delete operation in mysql.

id column in mysql is primary key.

[image]

A lot of null primary key found in corresponding hive table.

[image]

Comment: 1. can you pls check if your data has new line character in any field? you can resolve this by using `--hive-delims-replacement "xx" \`` and then replace xx with '\n' or '\t'. 2. just pull few columns to check if data is correctly extracted. 3. pull only required columns by mentioning `-- columns  col1,col2,col3,col4` clause will help as well.

Comment: OK. I will have a try and  feedback. Currently I use "where primary key is not null" condition to solve this issue. I still need  to find the reason. @KoushikRoy

Comment: Data may have new line character in it. Pick up a primary key from where null data starts in hdfs. Go to source and select data for that pk. Then export the data into notepad and check manually if you have any newline in the data. Not saying full proof but its one of the clerical way to find out the reason.